# Python `argparse` does not get any arguments if script is not run with `python file.py`

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm using `argparse` very simply like this:

```
#file.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The problem comes when running the file from the command line: if i run it with `python file.py --test` the arguments are passed correctly, but if i run it like `file.py --test` no arguments are passed.

I usually run some files in the latter way because I add them to the windows path to run them anywhere without limitations. Is there a way I can pass the arguments so that they are recognized?

Comment: That's odd. I used the given code, but it  worked for me...

Comment: @kostis1101 are you on windows?

Comment: yes, I am on windows 10. (python 3.8.5)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that there is no shebang of your file. I added shebang and it works for me.
test.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--test", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.test)
```

Run with `python3 test.py --test`
The output:

```py
True
```

Run with `./test.py --test`
The output:

```py
True
```

Remember to make sure your file is executable in both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thanks, though It still doesn't work. I'm using Anaconda for Windows so I used a different shebang (which might be faulty anyway). I'm not sure this is the problem anyway: the shebang is not needed when windows already knows how to open `.py` files.